# Showing detail page after search in Flutter not working

Tags: wordpress, flutter, api, rest, dart

I am trying to mix two things and that is horribly going wrong. Thought I could pull it off, but nope.

1. I am using a separate search functionality that checks my URL to
   fetch the posts
2. I am using the WP post service to fetch my posts

Now, I don't know how to combine the two so that when the search is finished, when you click on the search result, it should go to the post detail page (which works on my home screen, but not with search).

Example of `search.dart` - where I can't link to the post detail page.

```
                    ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SinglePostPage(
                              post:  userLists[index].text, // THIS IS THE DETAIL PAGE LINK I WAS TRYING TO USE, BUT NOT WORKING
                            )));
                      },


                      title: Text(
                        userLists[index].text,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),


                    )
```

Post page example:

```
class SinglePostPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final wp.Post post;

  SinglePostPage({Key? key, required this.post});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    );
  }
}
```

And:

```
PagewiseLoadController<Post> pagewiseLoadController = PagewiseLoadController(
      pageFuture: (pageIndex) {
        return PostService.instance.getPosts((pageIndex ?? 0) + 1, 10);
      },
      pageSize: 10);
```

And, with the link that works on home page but can't reproduce on search:

```
child: PagewiseListView<Post>(
            pageLoadController: pagewiseLoadController,
            itemBuilder: ((context, entry, index) {
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SinglePostPage(
                            post: entry,
                          )));
                },
```

How can I make the search functionality to send me to the right SinglePostPage?

Comment: Is `userLists[index].text` if correct type (`Post`)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually I am now thinking of just performing some kind of filter / search on ListTile, instead of fetching it separately from an API.  Perhaps that should be the question.